# NodeJS: get images files sizes in folder, compress if image is too big

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the image sizes in a folder, and then compress the images that are bigger than (for example: 2MB), the function getFilesizeInBytes is returning always size: 0, what i'm doing wrong?

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const imagemin = require("imagemin");
const imageminMozjpeg = require("imagemin-mozjpeg");
const imageminPngquant = require("imagemin-pngquant");
const imageminGifsicle = require('imagemin-gifsicle');


const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads/products');

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 

    files.forEach(function (file) {
        console.log(file); 
        console.log(getFilesizeInBytes(file))
    });
});


function getFilesizeInBytes(filename) {
    var stats = fs.statSync(directoryPath, filename);
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
    return fileSizeInBytes;
}


//Compress images

let compressPlugin = fileExt == 'jpg' || fileExt == 'jpeg' ? imageminMozjpeg({quality: 50}) : 
fileExt == 'png' ? imageminPngquant({quality: [0.5, 0.6]}) : 
fileExt == 'gif' ? imageminGifsicle() : 0;

(async () => {
    const files = await imagemin([`../uploads/products/${fileName}`], {
    destination: "../uploads/products",
    plugins: [ compressPlugin ]
    });
    fs.unlink(filePath, err => err ? console.log(err) : 0);
    return res.status(200).send({product: productUpdated});                     
})();
```

Comment: I think i was reading the folder instead the files... i modify this line and is working now: var stats = fs.statSync(directoryPath + '/' + filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue related to the wrong usage of the statSync function.
Please try to use this way:

```
function getFilesizeInBytes(filename) {
    var stats = fs.statSync(`${directoryPath}/${filename}`);
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
    return fileSizeInBytes;
}
```

For more information please check Node.js documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path_options)